# Can Android .APK files include Asset packs?

Tags: android, apk

When I try to build my app into an APK (to deploy without playstore to send to people for a study), it builds APK but it doesnt include my Asset Pack, which was needed because the game is 150MB+, too large for play store.

I have included my Asset pack in the build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    assetPacks = [":asset_pack_0"]
```

And the Asset packs build.gradle should also be correct. Asset pack is only included when building a .aab package but not an .apk.

```
assetPack {
packName = "asset_pack_0" 
dynamicDelivery {
    deliveryType = "install-time"
}
```

}

I found very little on this on google, maybe one of you has experience? Did you get including Asset packs in .APK bundles to work? Thanks.

Comment: Check out if this gist helps you.
https://gist.github.com/Farbklex/dbf96c2426c59a37d681438ade63e416

Comment: Define multiple flavors, one with asset_pack, one with everything included in the APK.